# Topologist's sine curve from Munkres book

Tags: general-topology

I was reading an example of connected but not path connected space from J.Munkres book and ran into two questions:

1) He claims that $f^{-1}(0\times [-1,1])$ has largest element. Is it because any nonempty, closed, bounded set on real line has maximal element, right?

2) We take $n\in \mathbb{N}$ how we can find $u$ s.t. $0<u<x(1/n)$ with $\sin(1/u)=(-1)^n$?

I guess since sequence $\dfrac{1}{\pi/2+\pi n+2\pi k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ and $n$ is fixed. Then we can take $u$ from this sequence. Is my reasoning correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, $A = f^{-1}(0 \times [-1, 1])$ is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function. Therefore it's closed. It's also bounded, since $\overline S$ itself is bounded. It follows that $A$ contains its least upper bound.

For your second question, your choice of $u$ works.